# Perl Net::Telnet sending CTRL+C

Tags: perl

I am using Net::Telnet in my perl script to login to Network device (Huawei Media gateway).
After running command I need to send "CTRL+C" character because few commands output are longer than the current screen size and for more output to be printed it is required to hit
CTRL+C from key board.

I tried searching net but no luck. Anybody has idea how to send this charater once it run a command.

Thanks in advance.

Regards
Mahesh

Comment: Did you see and try [this perlmonks node](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=359752)?

Comment: Even i also need to send CTRL+C in Net::Ping module, i tried with "\x03"...no luck :(

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just sending character with ascii code 3?

```
$t->print("\x03");
```

Comment: I tried the same but did't work. I used below lines but no luck   my @output1=$session->cmd('DSP PATCH:;');
$session->waitfor('/Press CTRL+C to break, other key to continue.../');
@output1=$session->print("\x03");
print @output1;

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but since I haven't seen anyone verify that any suggestion works, I figured I would reply.

This worked for me...

```
print $telnet->cmd("\x03");
```

Answer (score -1):

Thnx.

```
print $telnet->cmd("\x03");
```

worked for me as well.